# Identificar item selecionado ListView

Tags: c#

Tenho um `ListView` que carrega valores do meu banco de dados.
Gostaria de saber como faço para identificar o item selecionado para que eu possa recuperar o valor do campo `CODIGO_PRODUTO` e fazer um `UPDATE/DELETE` no banco de dados.

> Lembrando que minha `ListView` tem a opção de selecionar múltiplas linhas, basicamente preciso recuperar os `CODIGO_PRODUTO` de todas as linhas selecionadas para aplicar o `DELETE`.

```
private DataSet _dataSet;
private SqlDataAdapter _dataAdapterProducts;

public void getDados()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    string strSql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUTOS";
    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        _dataSet = new DataSet();
        _dataAdapterProducts = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, conn);
        _dataAdapterProducts.Fill(_dataSet, "PRODUTOS");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

private void carregaLista()
{
    getDados();

    DataTable dtable = _dataSet.Tables["PRODUTOS"];
    lvEstoque.Items.Clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow drow = dtable.Rows[i];
        if(drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
        {
            ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(drow["CODIGO_PRODUTO"].ToString());
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(drow["DESCRICAO"].ToString());
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(drow["QUANTIDADE"].ToString());
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(drow["VALOR_INICIAL"].ToString());
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(drow["VALOR_FINAL"].ToString());
            lvItem.SubItems.Add(drow["LUCRO"].ToString());
            lvEstoque.Items.Add(lvItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: você tem que usar os eventos `SelectedIndexChanged` ou `ItemSelectionChanged`

Comment: Vamos supor que tenho 10 produtos cadastrados, com Código de Produto do 1 ao 10, clico no produto de Código 5, como eu recupero esse valor 5? Poderia montar um bloco de código para eu ter base?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `SelectedIndexChanged`. Exemplo:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Código do produto escolhido: " + listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text);
    }
}
```

Mas, recomendo que utilize um `DataGridView` para esse propósito, e utilize também um `BindingList<>` para popular o mesmo. Irá simplificar seu trabalho.